# Is it better to import styles in angular.json or importing in styles.scss?

Tags: angular

I am trying to add ngx-datatable component to my project and I am learning to do this so I can eventually do this for a big project. There are two methods of adding styles to the datatable and one is by importing in `styles.scss`:

```
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/dark.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css';
```

And the other method is adding it to the `styles` array property in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/index.css",
              "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/material.scss",
              "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/dark.scss",
              "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/themes/bootstrap.scss",
              "./node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/assets/icons.css"
            ],
```

Which would be a better practice? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add your CSS imports in the `angular.json` file, think of it as adding multiple global css files for your project.

But if you add your CSS imports in the `styles.css` file, you will have one global stylesheet for your angular project but you will refer multiple stylesheets in it.

I personally refer my stylesheets in the `angular.json` file as I find it easy to maintain the custom global CSS that I write as apposed to importing multiple global CSS stylesheets such as `bootstrap`

Comment: How about the impact on hot reload compilation during dev? I assume angular.json is the more modular approach and leads to faster/small compiles if you edit css files during dev. Be good if someone could confirm though.

Comment: From my experience if you edit the angular.json, you'd have to recompile the application in order to observe the change.